# How to set image from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have the following aspx code

```
<asp:Image ID="pbScannedImage" runat="server" />
```

And my code behind c# code is

```
System.Drawing.Image image;
image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(dDSImageViewerDTO.ROI));
pbScannedImage.Visible = true;
pbScannedImage.ImageUrl = "";

// This is available but I don't want to write file to the disk and 
// assign directly to the image box something like 
pbScannedImage.Image = image;
//i know this is not possible so any other work around would be great help
```

So basically I want to assign the image to the image control without writing it to the anywhere else. Is it possible and if not then are there any workarounds for this available?

Comment: why don't you save `MemoryStream` in `session` and the using ashx return content of `MemoryStream`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind a MemoryStream to asp:image control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788/how-to-bind-a-memorystream-to-aspimage-control)

Comment: @ArjunVachhani session is not the way!

Comment: what is `dDSImageViewerDTO.ROI`

Comment: it's image in byte array

Comment: @Curiosity is it OK to save temporary `Byte []` in `Session` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pbScannedImage.Src = "ImageHandler.ashx";
```

And the handler code must be like:

name

```
 System.Drawing.Image dbImage =
                 System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("file path");
            System.Drawing.Image thumbnailImage =
                 dbImage.GetThumbnailImage(80, 80, null, new System.IntPtr());
            thumbnailImage.Save(mstream, dbImage.RawFormat);
            Byte[] thumbnailByteArray = new Byte[mstream.Length];
            mstream.Position = 0;
            mstream.Read(thumbnailByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(mstream.Length));
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(thumbnailByteArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can seperate your database image logic into a Generic Handler (ASHX) and then use the handler as your image's src e.g.

```
img.src=GetImage.ashx?id=1;
```

You'd need to create GetImage.ashx and handle your id's (or whatever your using) appropriately. Then you can do a simple write back to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Working off guymid's answer, you can also assign the img.Src from code behind like so...

```
pbScannedImage.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + ImageToBase64String(Image);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, especially if you want to ensure images are *never* cached (which is common with dynamically loaded images) is to add the image data as CSS background-image data to an element such as a div with:

"background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64," + ImageToBase64String(Image) + ")"

```
    public string ImageToBase64String(Image image)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

How  said @Sain Pradeep, you can create service(ashx or contoller method if you use mvc) for return image stream and use that with html tag `<img>`(asp:Image is wrapper over`<img>`).
See samples from [Display Image using ashx Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733875/display-image-using-ashx-handler)