# Elegant way to display images from SQL Server database in ExtJs Grid (C#)

Tags: c#, database, image, extjs, grid

I have some icons stored in database (i don't want the client to lose his icons, that's why i don't store them on disk - and some 5KB png's are not a big deal) which I need to be displayed in a grid, from where a user can either delete one ore upload some others.
I managed to display the icons in the grid by converting the binary image into its Base64 representation (on the server) like this:
(part of my JsonHelper, which returns the ExtJs grid store Json from a DataTable)

```
if (dt.Columns[j].DataType == Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"))
{
   byte[] byteArray = (Byte[])rows[i][j];
   //tempStr is the Json string i am building
   tempStr = tempStr.Replace(dt.Columns[j].ToString().ToLower(),
             Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length));
}
```

Then, on client side, in the grid I render the column icon like this:

```
renderIcon: function (value)
{
   return '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + value + '" style = "margin-left: 5px; height: 24px; width: 24px;"/>';
}
```

Everything works fine, but it seems to me it is not an elegant way (for example, if i want to select an icon from the grid and put it in a container, i have to add a label in that container with a html that 'points' to the image, since I don't have an actual image to work with an img xtype)

Can this be done in an more elegant/proper way ? I am using ExtJs 4.0.7, SQL server 2008 with asp.net.

Comment: What about providing a URL for the image xtype which points to a server side template that streams the image content?

Comment: What about storing the pngs on disk like everybody else and check them into code repo?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ASP.NET, the simplest way will be to create ashx handler. A sample implementation can be found at - [Display Image using ashx Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733875/display-image-using-ashx-handler)

With ashx handler, you can provide the URL in image's source.

Answer (score 0):

you save images name in app database and create a Get request form server to display image where you want to display.

Comment: I have the name of the images in the DB. So if I have 100 images to display in my grid, i will have to make 100 server requests ? So far, I simply have a ExtJs image component (or a label with <img> html) in my JS file. What I am supposed to do? How about the idea of saving the files locally and then return only the physical path to the images ?