# How to display images from a database (stored as byte[])

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to list an image on my page from a database. When I eval the image, it just displays the text `"System.byte"`.

Here is the code :

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="repCategory" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div id="DescofTiles">
             <p id="tiles1"><%#Eval("categoryID")   %>: </p>
             <p id="tiles2"><%#Eval("categoryName") %> </p>
             <br />
             <p id="tiles3"><%#Eval("Description")  %> </p>
             <br />
             <p id="tiles4"><%#Eval("Picture")      %> </p>
             <p id="tiles5">
                 <a id="udb" href="#">
                     <img src="Contents/images/update.png" /></a>
                 <a id="udb" href="DeleteCategory.aspx?id=<%#Eval("categoryID")%>">
                     <img src="Contents/images/delete.jpg" /></a>

                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"
                   OnCommand="LinkButton1_Click"
                   CommandArgument='<%#Eval("categoryID")%>'>
                   <img src="Contents/images/delete.jpg" alt="delete group" />
                 </asp:LinkButton>
             </p>
```

What should I do to make it appear as an image, instead of the text "System.byte"?

Comment: Can you show the code which you're using to get the image from the database

Comment: You can go with Handler. you will find any example in goolge

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have your images stored in a database and you are loading them into a `byte[]`. (Is that correct? It's not clear from your question).

Here are some options to display these images:

**store the image to a (temporary) file**

- write the data from the database to a file on your server, e.g:
- `File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/temp/image.png", byteArrayFromDb));`
- then add an `Image` control to your page and set the `ImageUrl` accordingly:
- `<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/temp/image.png` ... />`

**embed the image data in a data-URI**

- add an `Image` control to your page, e.g. `<asp:Image runat="server" id="img" .../>`
- in your code-behind, convert the `byte[]` to an image-URI:
- `img.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayFromDb);`

**serve the images through a HttpHandler**

- implement an HttpHandler which takes a query-string parameter (e.g. the primary-key of the image record)
- register the handler in your web.config file (e.g. under the name `ImageHandler.ashx`)
- use Image URLs such as `ImageUrl="ImageHandler.ashx?id=123"`
- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733875/display-image-using-ashx-handler) for more information

Comment: no the images are already in the database stored as byte array thanks i will try the second solution

Comment: A 3rd option would be to stream the image through a page... so you'd call `<img src="streamimage.aspx?id=123"/>` - and in `streamimage.aspx` you clear all response output, stream the image from the database with a content-type of `image/png`

Comment: @freefaller: or even better, a handler (*.ashx) - I'll add that to the answer